# Implementing a progress bar with MVVM / WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, backgroundworker

In WPF I have an application conforming to the MVVM design pattern. The majority of the work in this application is done within a Model, called like this:

```
CalculatorModel calculator = new CalculatorModel();
calculator.Execute();
```

In order to implement a progress bar I need to call this within the `DoWork` method of my background worker thread, then call `ReportProgress` when necessary.

The `Execute()` method looks something like this:

```
for(int x=0; x < 1000; x++){
   // perform function
}
```

How can I call ReportProgress from the CalculatorModel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Execute()` method can have an additional paramter of type `IProgress<T>`. The interface exposes `Report(T value)`.

```
internal void Execute(IProgress<int> progress)
{
    for(int x=0; x < 1000; x++){
        progress.Report(x);
        // perform function
    }
}
```

On client side, where you want to inform the user of any progress, you can subscribe to `ProgressChanged` event. Or, you can pass a delegate to Progress class constructor:

```
// Create the progress object.
Progress<int> progress = new Progress<int>((result) =>
{
    this.MyMethodToDisplayProgressToUser(result);
});

// Pass it to your method.
Execute(progress);
```

Note the `IProgress<T>` is a generic interface so instead of `int` you can have your reports e.g. in `string` format saying "Just started...", "Half of the job is done...", and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Just create the properties inside the viewmodel(model) class:

```
public Int32 WorkTotal {get {...} private set{...}}
```

and

```
public Int32 WorkDone {get {...} private  set {...}}
```

Set the `WorkTotal` before starting the job, then inside your worker method just change the `WorkDone` value. No thread synchronization is needed - WPF handles binding with correct dispatching code.

Your viewmodel(or model) class should [implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967052/wpf-simple-binding-to-inotifypropertychanged-object) the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx) and these properties
should notify the listeners using the PropertyChanged event. Also you

Then you just bind ProgressBar properties to the properties in your viewmodel:

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding WorkTotal, Mode=OneWay}" Value="{Binding WorkDone , Mode=OneWay}">
```

Comment: would go with a variation of this -> I use mvvm light, and would use messaging for sending receiving the progress from my DAL, and bind to some properties in the ViewModel that gets updated through the message system

Comment: Well, Piotr's solution will make your model a bit less coupled with view-related code. His solution also allows to remove the state from the model.